# How to add a custom property to a typescript interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-logger

**EDITED THE EXPLANATION:**

First, I am new to typescript so I am sorry if this a very basic question.  I am using an existing library (ngx-logger) that I can't/want to modify.  I am trying to create a service that returns a logger object configured to a specific logging level:

```
public getLogger(name: string): NGXLogger {
    
    // if the logger is defined, then create a new one and update its config
    if (name in this.logCfg['loggers']) {
        // using a deep copy so only this logger is affected
        let logger = _.cloneDeep(this.rootLogger);
        let level = this.getLevel(this.logCfg['loggers'][name]['level']);
        let config = this.rootLogger.getConfigSnapshot();
        config.level = level;
        // THIS IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO
        config.name = name;
        logger.updateConfig(config);
        return logger;
    }
    // was not found so use root logger
    return this.rootLogger;
}
```

this.logCfg is just a JavaScript object with the name and level of some of the critical components of the application and it looks like:

```
{
"loggers": {
    "DatasetListComponent":{
      "level": "INFO"
    },
    "DspService":{
      "level": "WARN"
    },
    "UserPreferencesLayoutFormComponent":{
      "level": "WARN"
    },
    "RoleListComponent":{
      "level": "DEBUG"
    },
    "SnapFileListComponent":{
      "level": "TRACE"
    },
    "SnapFileService":{
      "level": "TRACE"
    }
}
```

By being able to set the verbosity level to different levels, I would be able to debug issues quicker.  Each one of the classes specified above will call the service to get their own logger configured to the appropriate level using `this.service.getLogger(this.constructor.name);` call.

I would like to be able to add the name of the logger to the config object which is an interface.  The problem is that if I extend the interface, the line "logger.updateConfig(config)" would not work because the type is different, right?

The reason why I want to store the name of the logger is to be able to add that information to the metadata being printed every time the methods debug|info|warn|error are called.  Hope this makes more sense

Comment: The point of an interface is to make a contract for the expected data type. Don't break the contract - otherwise you'll have to lie about the type and this may lead to hard to debug errors. You can always return an object consisting of a `{ name, logger }`

Answer (score 2):

```
export interface CustomConfig extends ObjectConfig {
   name: string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  How do I deal with the library returning an ObjectConfig using a method (this.obj.getConfig())?  How can I then do this.obj.setConfig(config)?  It would expect an ObjectConfig and not a CustomConfig, correct?

Comment: `config as unknown as ObjectConfig` maybe? Hard to tell without a minimum reproducible example. Or at least complete code posted. And also out of scope from your original question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Still missing a lot of code. Like what is logCfg? And there is nothing called ObjectConfig in NGXLogger. Perhaps you mean https://github.com/dbfannin/ngx-logger/blob/master/src/lib/config/iconfig.ts Seems like what your question is really asking is how to track a logger by name. And for that you should use a custom message, IMO. https://github.com/dbfannin/ngx-logger/blob/master/docs/customising.md